# Programming concept regarding objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a confusion regarding programming. What difference does it make in terms of memory if we do this in objective-c:

```
+(NSString *)getName {
  NSString *name = @"Hello";
  return name;
}

OR

+(NSString *)getName {
  return @"Hello";
}
```

Is both same or is there any difference in terms of speed and performance?

Comment: These two, once optimised, should result in the same code.

Comment: actually i thought that the 1st one will initiate an string object and
then store info in it and then return it but the second will not create a string object.

Comment: That object is never used or referenced anywhere, so it's going to be removed during optimisation.

Comment: As a side note, getters in objective-C are named without 'get'. So your getter would be called -(NSString *)name;

Comment: You might find these wiki pages interesting: [Program Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) and [Optimizing Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)

Comment: Both reflects same only..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler will optimize the first example into the second example since the variable isn't used for anything else. So they are equivalent: none is faster, none saves any memory.

**Edit:**

So, I actually tried it and compared the assembler output.

Code used:

```
@implementation Test

- (NSString *)test1 {
        NSString *variable = @"Hello1";
        return variable;
}

- (NSString *)test2 {
        return @"Hello2";
}

@end
```

Compiler used:

> Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0

With no optimization (`-O0`), `test1` does indeed have code for the unused variable (`movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)` and `movq    -24(%rbp), %rax`, so one additional memory write and read). But already at `-O1` the variable is optimized away (as are the reads for the internal `self` and `_cmd` variables).

So in other words: with `-O0` (no optimization), `test1` is indeed slower than `test2`. But if optimizations are switched on, they are equivalent and result in the same code.

Comment: Thanks for clear me ... :) i thinking that first one create object of string which useless.